# atom editor has been automatic close on window 10?

Tags: atom-editor

I used to Atom editor for coding Golang, PHP,...
When I am coding, sometimes it is automatic close. I install it on Window 10.
Maybe when I switch tab or move mouse but I don't know why so.
**UPDATE**:
Version: 1.18.0 (before, it is older version but It also so)

Atom    : 1.18.0

Electron: 1.3.15

Chrome  : 52.0.2743.82

Node    : 6.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any more information? Anything special you did when installing? Have you followed the suggestions in the [Debugging document](http://flight-manual.atom.io/)? Also, could you give the following information?

- Which version of Atom are you using? 
  Can you reproduce the issue after completely exiting Atom and restarting using **atom --safe**?

Comment: does Atom still crash in safe mode (**atom --safe**)?